Specific mathematical constraints when flattening space in York decomposition
In the York decomposition of differential geometry, considering the transformation:
$$g_{ij} = \phi^4 \bar{g}_{ij}$$
When we explicitly set $\bar{g}_{ij} = \delta_{ij}$ (forcing flat space), what specific differential equations must a compensating vector field $T^i$ satisfy to preserve the original geometric information?
Specifically:
Given that the original metric must satisfy Einstein's constraint equations:
$$D_j(\frac{1}{2N}(K^{ij} - g^{ij}K)) = 0$$
What is the explicit form of the conservation equation for $T^i$ in flat space coordinates?
I've worked out that $T^i$ should satisfy something like:
$$\nabla \cdot (\phi^2 T) = 0$$
But I'm unsure if this is complete or correct.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
